# Disable redirect to login page and throw 404 if not logged in Yii

Tags: php, yii

How I can disable redirecting to login page for some controllers in Yii and throw 404 (or other) errors, for non-authorized users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `CController::beforeAction()` method in your master controller, which can be found at **/protected/components/Controller.php**:

```
class Controller extends CController {

    public function beforeAction() {

            // Allow guests to use actions in SiteController only
            if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest && $this->id != "site")
                throw new CHttpException(404);

            // Optionally include code here if its an authenticated user
            return true;
    }
```

Make sure all your other controllers extend from this controller. E.g.:

> class PageController extends **Controller** {

Also, make sure `&& $this->id != "site"` exists in the code above, otherwise users will never be able to reach the login page to login, or even view the homepage!